# Why @PathVariable trims the data containing #?

Tags: java, spring, spring-restcontroller

I have a `URI` mapping in my custom controller given below :

```
http://localhost:8080/abc/{id}
```

Now, for normal values in `id`, it's not creating any problem.

When id contains a `#`, the content gets trimmed.

For example: for `id = 123#qqq`, then `@PathVariable` makes it `123`

How to resolve this issue ?

Comment: `#` is a special character. You need to uri escape it.

Comment: why do you need to insert `#` ? if you want to append multiple value, use `queryString`

Comment: Basically, something like `index.html#abc` means `index.html` at id `abc`. The same is the case with query strings.

Comment: Isn't '#' an anchor...a place within the resource, like a place on a web page.?  So then it is being stripped because it isn't part of the specification of the resource itself.  Maybe this will be enough justification to escape it.

Comment: The same (explanations) would hold for `/` in a path variable. Though for URL parameters one could use `URLEncoder.encode(pathVar, "UTF-8")` here I would definitely refrain from problematic chars.

Comment: This is fundamental to how URIs and HTTP work and has nothing to do with Spring. If you examine your Network tab, you'll see that your browser doesn't even transmit that part.

Answer (score 0):

You basically have 2 options:

## 1) Keep `id` as Path Variable and escape the `#`

As already mentioned in the comments `#` is a special character in URIs normally reserved to refer anchor positions on the webpage. If you want to use it as a path variable you will have to escape it:

```
http://localhost:8080/abc/123%23qqq
```

Will yield your desired `id = 123#qqq`

## 2) Use a Request Parameter instead

This seems to to me the cleaner solution. If you have to have the `#` as part of your id, you should propably just encode it as a String in a request parameter:

```
public void fooBar(@Requestparam String id) {
   // do stuff
}
```

This way you won't have to worry about URI encodings since your `#` character will be interpreted as a String.